# How to read text file in Android?

Tags: android

I am saving details in out.txt file which has created a text file in data/data/new.android/files/out.txt.
I am able to append information to the text, however, I am unable to read this file. I used the following procedures to read the file :

```
File file = new File( activity.getDir("data", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE), "new/android/out.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Can anyone please help me out to fix this issue ?

Regards,
Sunny.

Comment: what means "unable to read this file"?

Comment: I mean, I am trying to read the contents from the file out.txt

Answer (score 14):

@hermy's answer uses `dataIO.readLine()`, which has now deprecated, so alternate solutions to this problem can be found at [How can I read a text file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-to-read-text-file-in-android). I personally used @SandipArmalPatil's answer...did exactly as needed.

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
try {
     File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     File file = new File(sdcard,"testFile.txt");

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  
     String line;   
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
     }
     br.close() ;
 }catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();           
 }

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.amount);  
tv.setText(text.toString()); ////Set the text to text view.
```

Answer (score 13):

You can read a line at a time with this:

```
FileInputStream fis;
final StringBuffer storedString = new StringBuffer();

try {
    fis = openFileInput("out.txt");
    DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(fis);
    String strLine = null;

    if ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
        storedString.append(strLine);
    }

    dataIO.close();
    fis.close();
}
catch  (Exception e) {  
}
```

Change the if to while to read it all.

Comment: openFileInput doesn't work

Comment: also readline is deprecated, so don't use above

Answer (score 9):

Just put your file (ie. named yourfile) inside the res/raw folder (you can create if if doesn't exist) inside your project. The R.raw.yourfile resource will be automatically generated by the sdk.
To obtain a String of the text file, just use the code suggested by Vovodroid in the following post:
[Android read text raw resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file)

```
 String result;
    try {
        Resources res = getResources();
        InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);

        byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
        in_s.read(b);
        result = new String(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        result = "Error: can't show file.";
    }
```