# java android - how to set html from resources to TextView?

Tags: java, android, html, textview

Is there any possibility to load html from res/raw into the TextView?
I know I can use WebView, but damn transparency is not always working (not on every device)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(readTxt()));
```

//This function will return string which you can set in your textview. And that String have html codes so use **Html.fromHtml**

```
 private String readTxt() {
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.My_html_file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The result shocked me :) it definately doesn't look like it looked in html

Comment: well yes, my issue is resolved - It's impossible to make textview's html look like webview's html - the text is formatted differentely

Answer (score 4):

You can put your html content in a `string` resource and use it in your TextView by :

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResource().getString(R.string.my_html)));
```

To format your HTML in strings.xml file, use that syntax :

```
<string name="my_html">
    <![CDATA[
    Your html content here
    ]]>
</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple HTML content you can use .setText(Html.fromHtml("**Hello** world!")). Just need to [load html file to string from raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420293/reading-android-raw-text-file).