# storing a .txt file in android

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a .txt file in android that I want to read. I first stored it in a raw directory but now I want this file in many languages and android to read the good file according to the language of the device. Do you know where and how I should store this file?

Comment: By the way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420293/reading-android-raw-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your default text file — that you want to use if nothing else matches — in `res/raw/` as you are now.

Store translations of the file to other languages in peer directories (e.g., Spanish in `res/raw-es/`).

This is how string resources work in `res/values-.../` directories. You are simply applying the technique to text files in `res/raw-.../` directories.