# file not found with DocumentBuilderFactory

Tags: android

Before posting this question i had search all the places to get some similar question, I had found questions but no answer worked for me, I used getResources, that approach also gave me a error saying Undefined Method, using this or Context also dint work, I just need to read and write a xml in android app and the xml should be stored in my app in res folder or any other folder which is standard, Right now i am using the below code, Please help  me with this. Thanks a lot ..Max

```
                DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("savecredentials.xml"));
```

Using getResources doesnt help, How to use getResources when it is undefined, and if i use context it doesnt work , Any simple solution for this one.

Comment: ok, can you add whole code for class and activity also for xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You had write `new File("savecredentials.xml")` which means you are reading `savecredentials.xml` from application folder.You had not set path of `res` folder.
You have to mentioned path from where you are reading file.

For example if you had a file in asset folder then you can write

```
    AssetManager mg = getResources().getAssets();
            InputStream myInput = null;
            try {
                myInput = mg.open("File name");
                if(myInput != null) {
                    System.out.println("File exists in assets");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("File not exists in assets");

            }

XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = null;
xpp = factory.newPullParser();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(myInput);
xpp.setInput(reader);
int eventType = 0;
eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
```

This code is for check weather file is exist in asset or not ?

And read from `res` folder

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-txt-raw-resource-file/5675934#5675934)

Comment: what is c in the above context, Also i dont have a database to open I have a xml file. and then i need to use the Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("savecredentials.xml")); , can you suggest me something in the above context.

Comment: getResouces method is undefined, Using Context or this also doesnt work.

Comment: please read my previous comment and the question i already mentioned that Context is not working.

Comment: getResources() method is for context class so you have to make object and then you have to call this method it will worked for you

Comment: not working please mention what to do with the context, is it Context c = new Context();

Comment: Are you writing this code in Activity, Service or any where else ?

Comment: not in the activity class, its in a class which is written just to handle xml read and write.

Comment: pass the reference of your Activity to that class and using that activity  reference call getResources() method in that class.