# Where to place the 'assets' folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-assets

I am confused about the `assets` folder. It doesn't come auto-created in Android Studio, and almost all the forums in which this is discussed talk about Eclipse.

How can the Assets directory be configured in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1826, accepted):

Since Android Studio uses [the new Gradle-based build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), you should be [putting `assets/` inside of the source sets](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure) (e.g., `src/main/assets/`).

In a typical Android Studio project, you will have an `app/` module, with a `main/` sourceset (`app/src/main/` off of the project root), and so your primary assets would go in `app/src/main/assets/`. However:

- If you need assets specific to a build type, such as `debug` versus `release`, you can create sourcesets for those roles (e.g,. `app/src/release/assets/`)
- Your product flavors can also have sourcesets with assets (e.g., `app/src/googleplay/assets/`)
- Your instrumentation tests can have an `androidTest` sourceset with custom assets (e.g., `app/src/androidTest/assets/`), though be sure to ask the `InstrumentationRegistry` for `getContext()`, not `getTargetContext()`, to access those assets

Also, a quick reminder: assets are read-only at runtime. Use [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), or [the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) for read/write content. (note: the first two links are to my blog)

Comment: I am trying to include a custom font in the assets directory. Should I be good to go by just pasting the .ttf file as src/main/assets/font.ttf ? or do i need to assign the font explicitly by code to the control to see it?

Comment: @kalehv: "or do i need to assign the font explicitly by code to the control to see it?" -- oh, absolutely. You will need to call `setTypeface()` on all `TextView` widgets (and others that inherit from `TextView`) that you want to use this particular font.

Comment: Cool. That worked like a charm. I wish there was a way to include Assets font (custom) into Styles.xml rather than using it through code. 

(My wish might sound too dumb to handle, I am a beginner so excuse me if it is :-P)

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for hours for this. I tried creating a sub directory for assets under /src/main/res/ and the directory was being removed from the apk build.

Comment: Jeez. The android documentation needs to be way more explicit about this kind of stuff. This was unnecessarily hard to find.

Comment: how to read a file once assets folder is created .                                                      InputStream stream = getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets().open("countries.txt");  It gives me filenotfound excepton

Comment: @Bora: Then you do not have `countries.txt` in the `assets/` directory. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) that, among other things, copies a file from assets into internal storage. If you have further concerns, please ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve].

Comment: This answer is no longer exactly accurate, as the way Android Studio renders the file structure has changed.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos: No, this answer is still accurate, as I am referring to the filesystem (in Android Studio, you get a filesystem view through the Project rendition of the explorer tree).

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I agree. However, running under a completely default Android Studio 2.2.2, you don't get the exact File Structure on the Project navigator. That's what I intended to point out.

Comment: On newer versions of Android Studio, there is no more src folder, see below answer for Android Studio to create it for you automatically.

Comment: @LarryJing: There is a `src` folder in any standard Android Studio project, including those created in Android Studio 3.1.2 and the current canary release of 3.2.

Answer (score 1633):

***Let Android Studio do it for you.***

1. In Android Studio (*1.0 & above*), right-click on the [image] folder and navigate to the *`Assets Folder`*.

[image]

2. On the next screen just click *`Finish`*.

[image]

And voila! It will create the *`assets`* folder in the *`main`* target source set.

[image]

Comment: this solution is for Android Studio 1.0 and above. Other answers are obsolete.

Comment: Graphical illustration makes all the difference in the world!

Comment: Problem: on newer versions of Android Studio (I'm using 2.1.2), empty asset folders are not displayed in the Project Files window, making it difficult to add files. :(

Comment: @ScottBiggs Once you add the _assets_ folder as shown above (on v2.1.2), it should be visible inside _app > src > main_

Comment: What would be the link to this folder in a java file?

Comment: @VeeK For e.g. if you need to access `assets>fonts` you would do something like: `Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/myfont.ttf"));` So a call to `getAssets()` will give you path to directories inside `assets` folder.

Answer (score 131):

Looking inside the .iml file of your project you will see the following line:

```
 <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
```

This means the "assets" folder is already declared for Gradle. You will need to create it under `src/main/` (I'm using Android Studio 0.4.2).

Comment: My .iml doesn't have this, what portion of the file do I add this to?

Comment: you probably have 2 .iml files, check both of them.

Comment: check app.iml not <Project-Name>.iml

Comment: Allways in .im at root of you src.. not in the project directory.. Thats just for gradle stuff.

Answer (score 95):

Select the `app` folder and then:

**`File`** > **`New`** > **`folder`** > **`assets Folder`** ,

[image]

the default location is inside `/main` folder

[image]

Comment: This is the TL;DR version of the accepted answer and is actually useful.

Answer (score 67):

First of all the "Assets" folder will not be created automatically with the project. We have to create it.

The location of Assets folder is: **App > src > Assets**

Please have a look of the simple image below.

[image]

**Note:** For creating assets folder just click on Project => Right click => Select New => Folder => Assets. It will create Assets folder.

Comment: If another newbie was confused by all these answers like me, the folder structure can look different based on the selection in the top left corner. Mine was "Android" while all the people here are using "Project" or "Project Files".

Comment: project structure is different based on what you select for Project structure, project, project files, packages, Android etc, but you follow the screens what I share and see the selection of project structure type.

Answer (score 43):

It's simple, follow these steps

**File > New > Folder > Assets Folder**

**Note :** App must be selected before creating folder.

Answer (score 31):

In android studio you can specify where the source, res, assets folders are located.
for each module/app in the build.gradle file you can add something like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this necessary if one follows the convention?

Comment: This is super useful if your project isn't crated from Android Studio's template (e.g. cloned from AOSP source code)

Answer (score 30):

Simply, double shift then type **Assets Folder**

choose it to be created in the correct place

Comment: Simplest One! (Y)

Comment: This a secret one. Wow. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Click over main → new -> directory → and type as name "assets"

or... main -> new -> folder -> assets folder (see image)

[image]

Answer (score 21):

In Android Studio 4.1.1

Right Click on your module (app for example) -> New -> Folder -> Assets Folder

[image]

Answer (score 18):

***Project -> app -> src -> main -> RMB(right mouse button) -> New -> Directory:***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 16):

**File > New > folder > assets Folder**

[image: Assets Folder]

Answer (score 13):

Two ways:

1. Select app/main folder, Right click and select New => Folder => Asset Folder.
   It will create 'assets' directory in main.
2. Select main folder, Right click and select New => Directory
   Enter name as 'assets' = > Ok.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

If you tried all your bullets in this thread in vain  try cleaning your project . In my case it  only worked after `Projet` -> `clean`

Answer (score 12):

right click on app folder->new->folder->Assets folder->set Target Source set->click on finish button

Answer (score 9):

Put the **assets** folder in the `main/src/assets` path.

Answer (score 8):

```
Src/main/Assets
```

It might not show on your side bar if the app is selected. Click the drop-down at the top that says android and select packages. you will see it then.

Answer (score 7):

When upgrading to the release version of Android Studio, you may be automatically switched to the new Android project View (see [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-androidview.html) for more info). If you swap back to either the Project or Packages view, you should see the standard folder hierarchy of a Gradle-based project. Then refer to [CommonsWare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302624/2911458) for the appropriate location.

Answer (score 7):

need configure parameter for gradle
i hope is will work

```
// file: build.gradle  
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/res/icon/', 'src/main/assets/']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio, click on the `app` folder, then the `src` folder, and then the `main` folder. Inside the main folder you can add the assets folder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12416138)

Comment: In Android Studio click on app folder, then src folder, then main folder . Inside main folder you can add Assets folder.

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1 : Go to Files.
Step 2 : Go to Folders.
Step 3 : Create Assets Folder.**

In Assets folder just put fonts and use it if needed.

Answer (score 5):

```
follow these steps 

1)file->New->Folder
 there are multiple options like
      aidl folder
      assets folder
      jni folder
2) choose options assets folder
3) then there is option to change path of assets folder if you 
    want to change then check otherwise left that checkbox of cahnge folder location
4) click on finish
```

Answer (score 5):

You easily adding an assets folder using Android Studio like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Either create a directory under /app/src/main or use studio File-> New -> Folder - > Assets Folder.

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio right-click Folder in app->src->main then create new DIRECTORY name that `assets`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that nobody mentioned this:
You can define it in **Project Structure** > **Project Settings**:

[image]