# How to have a textview with DIGITAL characters

Tags: android, textview

with android studio I have a textview that is the text of my countdown timer. I want to have that text view with digital characters. Can you help me?

Comment: Get time from timer and set it to textView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the font of the text of text view.

First put the font in your **asset** folder.

Then in your java file add code like this to change your font:

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                    "Digital.ttf");
TextView digital= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textView);
            digital.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Put Digital.ttf in your asset folder of your project.

This will might help you.

Comment: How to put the font in my asset folder?

Comment: @user2675569 search in google for `digital font .ttf`..download the .ttf file..and paste it to assets folder

Comment: Yes but I meant where is the asset folder?

Comment: @user2675569 In root project folder..Check this.. http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/android_using_external_fonts.png

Comment: Well you can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: I put the ttf in the asset folder as digital.ttf and used the code as indicated but at runtime I get a NullPointerException on the setTypeface() line.

Comment: Check the case as well... digital.ttf or Digital.ttf @LordofScripts

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this ...
place the ttf file in the `assets` folder and do the following code

```
 /**Font Typeface***/
        String fontPath = "fonts/DS-Digital.ttf";

    /**Font Typeface***/
    tf  = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
```

and then finally set it to textview

```
TextView wordtext;
wordtext.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the fonts from below link

http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/LED.Font/
http://www.fontspace.com/download/13974/c46cca08c1d746a1836e0080c24de5c2/wlm-fonts_lets-go-digital.zip

and crate a Assets folder paste it in ASstest folder of your app
Now in Activity

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Digital.otf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
tv.setTypeface(tf)
```