# Where should we put database file on Android studio?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, assets

I put database file in the folder `assets` on Android Studio. I can't find a file explorer in Android studio like in Eclipse. I made this database on SQLite expert personal.

When I am launching my application there are errors - what should i do? Does anybody have any examples like this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I found this link to the answer:  [It says to check the app.iml folder to see the configuration path to the assets directory.  I saw that and made a new directory under Main and called it assets.][1]  Hope this helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

First of all, breathe.

It is going to be pretty hard to figure out exactly what happened to to file, given your description.  The good news is that it is pretty unlikely that it is actually gone.  You should just focus on locating it.

I suggest you use your OS' search to find the file.  On a *nux based system, from a command line at the root of the Studio project directory, type:

```
find . -name <mydatabasefile.db>
```

Windows has similar capabilities.

A Studio project tree is pretty small.  At very worst, you will need to open it in your OS file browser and look around.