# Placement of assets folder in Android Studio full release

Tags: android, android-studio

Quite a recent topic so can't find any information on this.

With the full release of Android Studio, the structure of the folders has changed.

Is anyone aware of where the assets folder should now be?

Thanks :)

Comment: The full release of Android Studio may have switched you to Android project View automatically. See [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-androidview.html) for more info. If you swap back to Project or Packages view, you should see the standard folder hierarchy of a gradle-based project.

Comment: That's it @stkent - it had and as I'm relatively new to Android Studio, I wasn't aware...I thought the structure had changed! CommonsWare - you marking this question wasn't really relevant to be honest, because I specifically said the folder structure had changed...

Comment: @stkent - put it as an answer, I think someone else may come across the same issue and it would help!

Comment: I can't add as an answer here because the question is now marked duplicate, but I'll add it to the duplicate question.

Comment: [Here's the answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio).