# Why i get this Type face init error in android?

Tags: android

I want use my font in project and write this code in android studio:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/behzadd.ttf");
        text.setTypeface(tf);
        text.setText("بهزاد");
```

i copy my `behzadd.ttf` font file in this path:

```
res/fonts/behzadd.ttf
```

but when i run the project i get this error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
            at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
```

how can i solve that?

Comment: Right Path is `Asset/fonts/behzadd.ttf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your font in the `assets` folder , so the path is : `assets/fonts/behzadd.ttf`

Comment: but i cant see assets folder in android studio

Comment: If not then create `assets` folder at `Project/app/src/main/`

Comment: create the assets inside the `src/main` folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio