# Referencing a file in android studio

Tags: java, android, file

I'm writting some code that uses a serialized file. The file is called **alcala.ser** and is in **utils**, a subfolder of **java**. The class calling the file is in the same folder. Here's the code:

```
InputStream file = new FileInputStream("/alcala.ser");
```

I also tried:

```
InputStream file = new FileInputStream("alcala.ser");
```

In both cases, I get

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /alcala.ser: open failed: ENOENT (No
>   such file or directory)

How should I reference the file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/alcala.ser` would be the root of the device... I doubt your file would exist  there anyways because write access is not allowed

Comment: You should [make an `assets` folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27673773/2308683) to store your files.

Answer (score 1):

> The file is called alcala.ser and is in utils, a subfolder of java.

Move the file out of there and into `assets/`. Then, use `AssetManager` to `open()` an `InputStream` on the asset.

Comment: But I can't reference a 'non-static' method from a 'static' context... any ideas?

Comment: @DanielHurtadoRamirez: If the method in question is `open()`, you get an `AssetManager` instance by calling `getAssets()` on a `Context`, such as an `Activity` or `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

Check External and Internal Storage option in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.
Depending on how do you want to handle privacy you have to chose one or the other.