# where to locate .mp3 file in android studio if no raw directory found?

Tags: android, android-studio

I didn't found raw directory in my android studio. Where can I add .mp3 file in Android Studio? I didn't find exact answer for this? Please answer this if anyone knows about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to place Assets folder in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't found raw directory in my android studio.

There are an infinite number of possible resource directories. Android Studio does not create all of them.

> Where can I add .mp3 file in Android Studio?

You can create a `res/raw/` directory yourself. Right-click over `res/` and choose "New > Android resource directory" from the context menu.

Or, you can create an `assets/` directory yourself, if there is none already in your module. MP3 files tend to work better as raw resources, as the various media APIs usually have hooks for working with raw resources.

Comment: Yes. I directly added in the folder like AndroidStudioProjects\Background\app\src\main\res\raw..Thanks