# load values of ArrayList file into a ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to load the data of ArrayList file into ArrayList, but i got this exception error:

```
07-07 16:52:21.741: W/System.err(1941): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT [Ljava.lang.Stri...@1:28 in java.io.StringReader@f7179f5) 
07-07 16:52:21.741: W/System.err(1941):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
07-07 16:52:21.743: W/System.err(1941):     at com.example.ActivityQuizScreen.addflags(ActivityQuizScreen.java:253)
07-07 16:52:21.743: W/System.err(1941):     at com.example.ActivityQuizScreen.onCreate(ActivityQuizScreen.java:108)
07-07 16:52:21.743: W/System.err(1941):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
07-07 16:52:21.743: W/System.err(1941):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
07-07 16:52:21.745: W/System.err(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
07-07 16:52:21.745: W/System.err(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
07-07 16:52:21.745: W/System.err(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
07-07 16:52:21.745: W/System.err(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
07-07 16:52:21.746: W/System.err(1941):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-07 16:52:21.746: W/System.err(1941):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-07 16:52:21.746: W/System.err(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
07-07 16:52:21.747: W/System.err(1941):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-07 16:52:21.747: W/System.err(1941):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
07-07 16:52:21.747: W/System.err(1941):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-07 16:52:21.877: W/EGL_emulation(1941): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-07 16:52:21.877: W/OpenGLRenderer(1941): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xac0b28c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-07 16:52:22.429: E/Surface(1941): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabff43b0
07-07 16:53:21.877: W/EGL_emulation(1941): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-07 16:53:21.880: W/OpenGLRenderer(1941): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xac0b2ee0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

the code is :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void addflags() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

    ArrayList<Flag> flagList = new ArrayList<Flag>();

    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource source = new InputSource();
    source.setCharacterStream(new StringReader((getResources().getStringArray(R.array.flags)).toString()));
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(source);  // ActivityQuizScreen.java:253 is about here
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for(int i = 0; i< nodes.getLength();i++)
    {               
       NamedNodeMap attr = nodes.item(i).getAttributes();

       String name = attr.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
       String CountryCode = attr.getNamedItem("pic").getNodeValue().toLowerCase();
    int pic = getResources().getIdentifier(CountryCode, "drawable", getPackageName());
    Flag flag = new Flag(
            attr.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue(),
            getResources().getIdentifier(CountryCode, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    flagList.add(flag);

    }
```

Array list file is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="flags"> 
    <item pic="AF"  name="Afghanistan"  />
    <item pic="AL"  name="Albania"  />
    <item pic="DZ"  name="Algeria"  />
    <item pic="AS"  name="American Samoa"  />
    <item pic="AD"  name="Andorra"  />
    :               :                :
    <item pic="YE"  name="Yemen"  />
    <item pic="ZM"  name="Zambia"  />
    <item pic="ZW"  name="Zimbabwe"  />
    <item pic="AX"  name="Åland Islands"  />

</string-array>
</resources>
```

How i can solve this, or is there better solutions to load arrayl list from a file?? Anyone plzzzzzz?

Thank you!!

Comment: You should read about resources on android, your code is rather odd

Comment: you mean  source.setCharacterStream(new StringReader((getResources().getStringArray(R.array.flags)).toString()))how i can take that resource properly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to create an assets folder:
[Where do I place the 'assets' folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio)

2) Add this xml file (Example name: flag_array.xml) in your assets folder:

resources>

```
<string-array name="flags">
    <item pic="AF"  name="Afghanistan"  />
    <item pic="AL"  name="Albania"  />
    <item pic="DZ"  name="Algeria"  />
    <item pic="AS"  name="American Samoa"  />
    <item pic="AD"  name="Andorra"  />
    <item pic="YE"  name="Yemen"  />
    <item pic="ZM"  name="Zambia"  />
    <item pic="ZW"  name="Zimbabwe"  />
    <item pic="AX"  name="Åland Islands"  />
</string-array>
```

/resources>

3) Replace your code in the addflags() method with this:

```
    ArrayList<Flag> flagList = new ArrayList<Flag>();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    try {

        db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("flag_array.xml");
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for(int i = 0; i< nodes.getLength();i++) {
            NamedNodeMap attr = nodes.item(i).getAttributes();

            String name = attr.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
            String CountryCode = attr.getNamedItem("pic").getNodeValue().toLowerCase();

            int pic = getResources().getIdentifier(CountryCode, "drawable", getPackageName());
            Flag flag = new Flag(
                    attr.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue(),
                    getResources().getIdentifier(CountryCode, "drawable", getPackageName()));
            flagList.add(flag);
        }

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!! but i want to place it in values for multi-language purposes, how i can keep it in values?

Comment: I have created another answer for multi-language purposes. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to perform XML parsing on a java string array.
I believe you're looking for something like:

```
ArrayList<String> flagList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.flags)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For multi-language purposes:

1) You need to create an assets folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio.

2) Add this xml file (Example name: flag_array.xml) in your assets folder:

resources>
    <string-array name="flags">
        <item pic="AF"  name="Afghanistan"  />
        <item pic="AL"  name="Albania"  />
        <item pic="DZ"  name="Algeria"  />
        <item pic="AS"  name="American Samoa"  />
        <item pic="AD"  name="Andorra"  />
        <item pic="FR"  name="French"  />
        <item pic="ES"  name="Spanish"  />
        <item pic="YE"  name="Yemen"  />
        <item pic="ZM"  name="Zambia"  />
        <item pic="ZW"  name="Zimbabwe"  />
        <item pic="AX"  name="Åland Islands"  />
    </string-array>
/resources>

3) In res folder, you need to create the values folders for each language: Example: values-es, values-fr, and in each value folder you need to create a xml with the strings that you want to translate.

4) In your ActivityQuizScreen Class, you can add a ListView:

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);


    And in the XML:

    <!--multiLanguageTextView is used to show the change in the languages-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/multiLanguageTextView"
        android:padding="32dp"
        android:text="@string/title" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/multiLanguageTextView"
        android:id="@+id/lvItems"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"/>




5) Replace your code in the addflags() method with this:

        ArrayList<Flag> flagList = new ArrayList<Flag>();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        try {

            db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream is = assetManager.open("flag_array.xml");
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(is);
            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for(int i = 0; i< nodes.getLength();i++) {
                NamedNodeMap attr = nodes.item(i).getAttributes();

                String name = attr.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
                String CountryCode = attr.getNamedItem("pic").getNodeValue().toLowerCase();

                int pic = getResources().getIdentifier(CountryCode, "drawable", getPackageName());
                Flag flag = new Flag(
                        name,
                        CountryCode,
                        pic);
                flagList.add(flag);
            }


            //Set ListView Custom Adapter
            FlagAdapterItem adapter = new FlagAdapterItem(MainActivity.this, flagList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

6) Custom Flag Adapter

public class FlagAdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter<Flag> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Flag> list;


    public FlagAdapterItem(Context context, ArrayList<Flag> list){
        super(context, 0, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Flag flagEntity = list.get(position);

        if (convertView == null)
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);

        TextView tvCountryName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCountryName);
        tvCountryName.setText(flagEntity.getName());

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setLocale(flagEntity.getCountryCode());
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    //Method to change the user LOCALE value (Example: fr, es)
    //After change it, the app going to read from de selected Locale automatically
    // (Example: values-es, values-fr).

    public void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (!conf.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

            //Refresh actual activity but you can go to the next activity
            ((Activity) context).finish();
            context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
        }
    }
}


7) FlagAdapterItem xml Layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCountryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tvCountryName" />
</LinearLayout>
```