# How can I store my files for reading later in Android

Tags: android, file

I am doing a quastion game like Bilioner game but its about a history lesson and there will be history questions and subject expressions, too. I think to store my questions in a file and take from this file. And my subject texts too. I dont use database(sqlite) I want to do it with file. I cant store in strings because  they are long. I am writing them to a txt file and I can read them from there. With code below:

```
   try {
                FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("abc.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
                OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
                outputWriter.write("asddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
                outputWriter.close();

                //display file saved message
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            try {
                FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("abc.txt");
                InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

                char[] inputBuffer= new char[1000];
                String s="";
                int charRead;

                while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
                    // char to string conversion
                    String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                    s +=readstring;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                InputRead.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

But I dont want to write to txt file. Because I cant write the data EVERYTİME. I want to just read them from an existing txt file. But I cant read without writing. Where should I place my txt file in Android app folder and how can I find them and after read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place it in res/raw folder. Then you can get an InputStream:

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
        getResources().getIdentifier("file",
        "raw", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: @Diego Laballos thank you I did it I am so happpy thank you :)))

Comment: what do you mean wiith assets @cricket_007 how can I do with this

Comment: @dds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio#18302624