# How to access local files other than JSON with react-native

Tags: react-native

I need to parse a local .csv file that I include somewhere between all the js files (like some kind of local ressource).
I found a library that does the job > Papaparse. But it seems like it can't "download" my local file due to incompatibilities with the Javascript-Environment.

I guess it would work if I can somehow just pass the content of my local csv file to papaparse as a string. But I can't figure out how to get the content of local csv-file inside a variable with react-native.
Any Suggestions?

**EDIT:**
I've tried it with react-native-fs. I put my csv-file under android/src/main/assets/ and try to access it with
`RNFS.readDirAssets('/');`

-> Output is this:
`08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS: [ { ctime: null,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     mtime: Invalid Date,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     name: 'AndroidManifest.xml',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     path: '//AndroidManifest.xml',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     size: 0,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isFile: [Function: isFile],
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isDirectory: [Function: isDirectory] },
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:   { ctime: null,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     mtime: Invalid Date,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     name: 'META-INF',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     path: '//META-INF',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     size: 0,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isFile: [Function: isFile],
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isDirectory: [Function: isDirectory] },
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:   { ctime: null,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     mtime: Invalid Date,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     name: 'assets',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     path: '//assets',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     size: 0,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isFile: [Function: isFile],
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isDirectory: [Function: isDirectory] },
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:   { ctime: null,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     mtime: Invalid Date,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     name: 'classes.dex',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     path: '//classes.dex',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     size: 0,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isFile: [Function: isFile],
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isDirectory: [Function: isDirectory] },
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:   { ctime: null,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     mtime: Invalid Date,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     name: 'lib',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     path: '//lib',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     size: 0,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isFile: [Function: isFile],
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isDirectory: [Function: isDirectory] },
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:   { ctime: null,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     mtime: Invalid Date,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     name: 'res',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     path: '//res',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     size: 0,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isFile: [Function: isFile],
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isDirectory: [Function: isDirectory] },
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:   { ctime: null,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     mtime: Invalid Date,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     name: 'resources.arsc',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     path: '//resources.arsc',
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     size: 0,
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isFile: [Function: isFile],
08-11 14:53:14.524 17058 17202 I ReactNativeJS:     isDirectory: [Function: isDirectory] } ]`

It seems like my assets folder is always empty.

Comment: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I've already tried with this library, but I did not figure out how to point to my csv file. Isn't it packaged inside my .apk if I put it together with the other js files?

Comment: There are usages examples in the README for iOS and Android.

Comment: I've found out now how to read the assets folder with react-native-fs. But I am not able to deploy my .csv file there. I've tried to place it in android/app/main/assets or even make a /assets folder in the root directory and link it with react-native link. The files inside there are never included as app assets.

Comment: I'm not an avid Android developer, but isn't there supposed to be an assets folder included with the default project template?

Comment: I guess there should be one, but in my case there wasn't. I've tried to manually create in and put the assets in there. But when i compile and let react-native-fs output the contents of the assets folder, it is always empty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: That's exactly where I've put it...

Comment: What have you tried and what happened? Compile error? Runtime exception?

Comment: I've put it in the main question.

Comment: Could you update the answer with the relevant parts of your program?

Comment: Regarding the console output, it just looks like a series of logging statements. The only vaguely suspicious detail is the value of `mtime`.

Comment: Thanks for your helping efforts, I've managed to solve the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to access my csv file:

Placed it inside:

```
android/app/src/main/assets/myFile.csv
```

(I've created the assets folder myself)

I was able to get the csv-data as string with the following code:

```
const csvFile = RNFS.readFileAssets('myFile.csv', 'ascii').then(file => {
            return file;
        });
```

In my case, the file was ascii-encoded, so I've put the encoding 'ascii' as second argument, otherwise I would get some error saying "invalid continuation byte".