# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, android

This exception keeps on appearing:

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name

this error has been seen on many other webpages on StackOverflow, but reading them all and testing the given suggestions didn't help me

[image]

the Activity looks like this:

```
package net.juntermanns.mitmatmaschrapport;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import static java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle;

public class DateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static ResourceBundle resourceBundle = getBundle("net/juntermanns/mitmatmaschrapportapp/src/resbundle.properties");
    final String TAG = ((resourceBundle.getString("dateactivity")));
    TextView textView;
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. This issue I have already took me 24hours. Do you mind writing a proper path for your suggested asset-folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multilingual apps, you can use [`strings.xml` files](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

So

```
res/values/strings.xml 
res/values-de/strings.xml
```

If you require ResourceBundle, you should create an `asset` folder, and load them via `getAssets()`

[Where do I place the 'assets' folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: already got this, the ResourceBundle is for non-internationalized strings.  No hardcoded strings - this is where the pain started.

Comment: Then what's the purpose of the suffixes? de and en?

Comment: differend languages do work within the app, the other kind of strings to be referenced do not.thank you. I am not sure about some strings, they are a couple of hundred, so I made different *.properties files.

Comment: Like I posted, assets should work. Just the src folder isn't copied directly into the app, so that resbundle folder does not exist

Comment: Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name net/juntermanns/mitmatmaschrapport/app/src/main/assets/resbundle.properties, locale

Comment: more slim and possible solution than using ResourceBundle, thanks!