# Android downloadable fonts using semi bold style

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-support-library, android-fonts, android-downloadable-fonts

I am using google downloadable fonts as given in below link

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html

I want to use Montserrat font style semi bold but that option is not there in android

Also in below link there is style semibold any idea how to do it

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat

following is my textview xml after adding font family

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="@string/address"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/title_light_color"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: what is the font name you are sending as a query parameter of *FontRequest* ? Is it "Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf" refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#programmatically

Answer (score 2):

You can download here all types of fonts `montserrat`

https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/ofl/montserrat

https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf

Add in your `res/font` folder use this

```
android:fontFamily="@font/Montserrat-SemiBold"
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new font in `res/font`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
    app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
    app:fontProviderQuery="name=Montserrat&amp;weight=600"
    app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

You can specify any supported weight by changing `weight` inside `app:fontProviderQuery` (`600` for semi-bold). Android Studio will raise a `FontValidationWarning`, but it will work nonetheless.

Source: [Google Fonts API for Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/android)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class named `FontCache`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class FontCache {
    private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<>();

    public static Typeface get(String name, Context context) {
        Typeface tf = fontCache.get(name);

        if (tf == null) {
            try {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

            fontCache.put(name, tf);
        }

        return tf;
    }
}
```

Then put the below lines of code in your activity:

```
Typeface montserratFontType = FontCache.get("fonts/montserrat.ttf", MainActivity.this);
yourTextView.setTypeface(montserratFontType);
```

At last, create an `assets` folder inside your main folder then create a `fonts` folder inside the `assets` folder and put your `montserrat.ttf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,
Create Customize font style for android app,

first create `assets` folder then create inside that `font` then put your downloaded font(ex: Light.ttf)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio)

Then add this line in activity

```
Typeface mycustomface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Light.ttf");
```

then declare that textview

```
textview.setTypeface(mycustomface1);
```