# Cannot set my custom font on View Android

Tags: android, view, fonts

I'm trying set custom font on TextView:

```
public void setHeaderTextWithKaushan (String text) {
    headerText.setText(text);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "font/kaushan.otf");
    headerText.setTypeface(face);
}
```

But I get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found font/kaushan.otf
```

I've read similar questions and some guys say to move fonts folder from `res`to `assets`, but I've opened project structure(*picture) an there is no `assets` folder.

[image: Project structure]

Which is the problem?

Comment: `there is no assets folder` then just create it. Fonts really have to be placed in assets, not in res

Comment: How do I can create it? By android studio or by Window File Manger?

Comment: any of you listed. Both will work\

Comment: If you are unsure where to create it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: thank you very much. it really works))