# Is there a directory for txt files just like drawable for images?

Tags: android, assets

In Android Studio, If we want to use an image in our Anroid app, we move this image to `res/drawable` file. And we use it.

But if we want to use contents of a `.txt` file (e.g reading text from file at the first launch the app), which directory should we move this file?

Comment: The assets folder

Comment: it create assets folder then move .txt files.

Comment: @mTak there is no `assets` folder in my file system of Android Studio project.

Comment: @BeStudios just create it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put it on `res/raw` or in `assets/` directory.

Comment: There is no `assets/` folder or `res/raw` folder in my file system of Android Studio project.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio.

Comment: You have to create for yourself. 
Here's how: Right click the res folder > New > Folder > Assets Folder/Raw Resources Folder.
As of now, Android Studio does not have specific folder for .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

Just create folder `assets` like this:

[image: like this]

Or create folder `raw` in `res` and you can put there whatever you want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on using file.For example for reading text file, any movement is needed. You can read it from asset directory.

But if you want to write in a text file, you must move it to internal/external memory in a directory you have set in your code.