# How to add a file in app directory?

Tags: android, file, android-studio, text-files

So, I have a txt file, and when my app starts, I want it to be added in the app directory. In other words, I want the txt file to be a part of the apk.

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 1):

You can put text file in your asset folder.

1. In Android Studio (*1.0 & above*), right-click on the [image] folder and navigate to the *`Assets Folder`*.

[image]

2. On the next screen just click *`Finish`*.

[image]

It will create the *`assets`* folder in the *`main`* target source set.

[image]

Details and image: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27673773/4972317)