# Play audio from assets with SQLite

Tags: java, android

My problem is that my code was not working. i have 100+ mp3 store in my assets/anthem folder.

```
flAnthem = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANTHEM));
flAnthemSDCard = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANTHEM_SDCARD));

AssetManager assetManager= getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;
try{
    inputStream = assetManager.open("anthem/" + flAnthem);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(inputStream));
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi, in what way is your code "not working"? Do you get any errors in Logcat?

Comment: i dont get any error. but its not playing the mp3

Comment: So the code doesn't fall into the `catch` block?

Comment: yes it does not .

Comment: Just double checking for any silly things, is the media file playable from another app or your PC? And is your volume at a correct level? Could you place a `Log.i` statement after `mediaPlayer.start()`, and see if it appears in Logcat? If your code is not going into the catch block then that suggests your code is running fine.

Comment: is my code right? or maybe not? because i only put the name of mp3 inside my database

Comment: I'd recommend reading up about [debugging with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#breakPoints) to make sure that your code does properly run through that `try` block. As it stands there isn't really enough information to answer your question well.

Comment: Give me a few hours and I'll try and recreate your issue when I'm at home using the code you've provided.

Comment: @jopo Check my answer

Comment: okay ill check it

Comment: thank u sir it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace this**

> ```
> inputStream = assetManager.open("anthem/" + flAnthem);
> mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(inputStream)); //DataSource is not correctly setted.
> ```

**By Using `AssetFileDescriptor`**

```
flAnthem = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANTHEM)) + ".mp3"; // don't forget extension 

AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("anthem/"+mediaName);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
```

**BTW**

- Check this question for more info about, [Where do I place the 'assets' folder in Android Studio?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: Could you please explain **how** this will help with OP's issue? Why are you adding an extra layer of complexity by taking the ringer mode into account? And OP is obtaining a resource using an `AssetManager`, not a resource ID.

Comment: I am updating my question now to fix this, Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @MichaelDodd I fixed my answer using `AssetFileDescriptor`, **BTW** i created a sample app and that worked my me.

Comment: what is timber for?

Comment: @jopo `Timber` is a Logger library by **JakeWharton** https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber

Comment: @MichaelDodd Thanks for your kindly feedback about answer shall be describe the OP's problem and step for fixing, Not just some code or another way for fixing the issue *(Like i did)*, Your suggestion will provide more help for OP and Others when search for same issue, But i intend to add more info when have time as update.

Comment: i remove timber and change it into e.printStackTrace(); , but it works fine

Comment: @jopo Updated my answer by replacing `Timber` with `ex.printStackTrace();` Happy that helped you.

Comment: @MichaelDodd Simplify my answer and described OP's issue, Waiting for yours Vote up :)

Comment: @KhaledLela Duely noted, thanks for making Stack Overflow a more helpful place for future readers ;)

Comment: hello, last night my mp3 is working but now why still playing when i click the next button.

Comment: i didnt change my code but my music still playing when i pressed next button. last night my mp3 is work when i play next it stop and when i guessed it will play the music

Comment: @jopo If old media keep running after pressing next button, You just need to stop old `mediaPlayer.stop();` before start playing new media `mediaPlayer.start();`

Comment: Is it going to stop because my next button is at my dialog box different activity/java

Comment: If you don't have globe reference to `MediaPlayer`, Then next button switch activity it will stop, Feel free to ask another question if you still have an issue.