# Files in java android

Tags: java, android, file

Some questions about working with files on android. Is it possible to read files from project? Like from "src" directory. Also, how should I create files?

```
File file = new File("a.txt");
try {
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Doesn't work here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I place the 'assets' folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: you can't read files from src ,res , assets or any other folder that in your development environment.if you want access src files simply use their class names, if you want use res files simply use R class that compiled for this reason. and don't put your plain texts or any other files into your src dir. they must be in assets folder

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of storage facility available for file saving
"internal" and "external" storage
To create a file internally

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

`getFilesDir()` returns a File representing an internal directory.

To learn more please go through https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files