# I don't have folder option

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi i wanted to make an assets folder but i have no option to do it , is it in another place , I've tried searching google but no results , also i tried installing tools in sdk manager with no luck  , is there anything to do maybe i missed something ,btw im a beginner

[image: Android Studio context menu]

i don't have  `file > new > folder`

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Choose directory from the menu. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, in the right-most fly-out menu, choose "Directory" to create a directory.

However, `assets/` goes in `src/`. So, right-click over `src/` for your desired source set, then choose File > New > Directory from the context menu.