# FileNotFoundException - Cannot import json with Room instance

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to populate my ROOM database with a simple JSON that I have inside the raw folder, this is my code

```
fun getInstance(context: Context): CarDatabase {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance =  Room.databaseBuilder (
            context,
            CarDatabase::class.java, "cars_table"
        ).createFromAsset("app/res/raw/cars_sample.json").build()
    }
    return instance as CarDatabase
}
```

And I get this

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: app/res/raw/cars_sample.json

Answer (score 0):

Unless your module has `src/main/assets/app/res/raw/cars_sample.json`, that is not a valid path within `assets/` to your JSON. And, since Android cannot find that JSON, my guess is your module does not have that asset.

From the looks of what you are using, my guess is that you are trying to populate your database from a raw resource. Raw resources are similar to assets, but they are not assets.

You will need to [create an `assets/` directory for your module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302624/115145) and move your JSON there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I think I cannot move the json to assets because my requirement is to populate my database from the raw resource folder, is there any way of doing it ?

Comment: @SNM: You could try using `openRawResource()` on `Resources` to get an `InputStream` and use that [with `createFromInputStream()` on `RoomDatabase.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#createFromInputStream(java.util.concurrent.Callable%3Cjava.io.InputStream%3E)). I have not tried that though.