# why I can't read json file in kotlin android project

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    val jsonString_ = File("C:/Users/admin/Document/sample.json").readText()
    System.out.println(jsonString_)

    //or this
    val jsonString = applicationContext.assets.open("../res/sample.json")
        .bufferedReader()
        .use { it.readText() }

    System.out.println(jsonString)
```

I tried both codes but I get "No such file or directory" or "java.io.FileNotFoundException" errors.I tried Intellij, it worked but it doesn't work on android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<application 
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/>
```

I added them to the manifest file,nothing changed.

Comment: Where are you running the code you mentioned? On your phone?

Comment: "but it doesn't work on android" -- `C:/Users/admin/Document/sample.json` is not a valid filesystem path on Android, and `"../res/sample.json"` is not a valid location inside your module's `assets/` directory.

Comment: @Julia Emulator

Comment: @CommonsWare "sample.json" or assets/sample.json" not work . assets file not found

Comment: Where *exactly* in your project is `sample.json`? For example, `C:/Users/admin/Document/sample.json` is not going to be [inside of your project, in an `assets` directory that you create](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302624/115145).