# Android Kotlin assert list is empty but file is in folder

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to read a file in via Android assets folder. For this I made a assets folder like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27673773/11419075). I made a file and it is shows in the explore:

[image]

When I run in the `onCreate` method:
`Log.d("Test", assets.list("/").contentToString())` The output is `[]`.

Also when I run:

```kotlin
assets.open("Injector.js").bufferedReader().use {
    Log.d("Test", it.readText())
}
```

The output is `""` or Nothing.

Is there anybody familiar with this issue or has any ideas how to resolve this?
If you need more information please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `applicationContext` like this:

```
applicationContext.assets.open("Injector.js").bufferedReader().use {
     Log.d("Test", it.readText())
}
```

Comment: You are a god! Thanks mate, works. For listing the files I had to use "" instead of "/"