# How to properly create a .txt file within the Android project directory (and be able to edit it)?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm new to Android. I searched for how to create a file within the Android directory and was lead to this post which mentions to save it to the assets directory: [Where to put text files in directory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120003/where-to-put-text-files-in-directory-in-android)

My problem is, turns out I cannot edit files which are in the assets directory.

`context.openFileOutput` saves it to what `context.getFilesDir()` returns, which is `/data/` folder (which from my understanding is not within the Project directory because I need to ask permission for it) but the problem I'm having with saving it there is that I get permission denied, even when I have permission to save (I made this post about it: [Getting a Permission denied error when creating a file with Android, even when permission is given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881576/getting-a-permission-denied-error-when-creating-a-file-with-android-even-when-p?noredirect=1))

With that said, what's the correct way to save a .txt file within the Android project directory but Not inside the assets folder?

Comment: what is the content of the .txt file?

Comment: Can you show us your piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. The "project directory" (this is basically the content of your APK that is installed on the device) is **read-only**. Android provides you with a number of places where you can write data:

- application-specific private data directory
- Shared preferences
- external storage (SD-card or similar)
- SQLite database