# Why do I get question marks instead of symbols when reading from .txt with InputStream?

Tags: android, character, inputstream

I know it must be obvious but can't find the answer.

What should I do to get the right characteres such as ", ', etc...?

This is the method I am using,

```
public void read(Context context) {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.puzzles);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
        scanner.useDelimiter(PATTERN);
        for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
            ids[i] = scanner.next();
            titles[i] = scanner.next();
            questions[i] = scanner.next();
            answers[i] = scanner.next();
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of research I finally found the answer.

First of all I created a BufferedReader from the InputStream for character reading instead of  raw byte reading.

Most importantly I instantiated the InputStream with the constructor with the charSetName.

If you go to 'Save as' in your NotePad you can choose your Encoding.

Finally I found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html) the supported encodings.

The default one in NotePad seems to be ANSI, which doesn't seem to be supported so I changed it and save my .txt file as UTF8.

Here is the code:

```
public void read(Context context) {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.puzzles);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream, "UTF8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Puzzle p = null;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(bufferedReader);
        scanner.useDelimiter(TOKEN);
        // Skips the first strange char
        scanner.next();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {

            p = new Puzzle();
            p.setId(scanner.next());
            p.setTitle(scanner.next());
            p.setQuestion(scanner.next());
            p.setAnswer(scanner.next());
            puzzles.add(p);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner object seems to recognize only letters and numbers by default... Try an approach without using the scanner like the answer to this question: [Android read text raw resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4087674/1267661)

And use String.indexOf(), or TextUtils.StringSplitter, or anything similar to read each line and parse the true strings between your tokens.

You might want to use a while loop to read data until the end of the file rather than a fixed number (70 in your case) for future puzzle files that may have more or less data.

Comment: Thanks @Sam, I'll definately go for an approach reading characters insted of bytes as said on your link, but still don't understand why I can't use Scanner. Where did you read that it only recognizes letters and numbers? Regarding the loop, you are absolutely right. I just didn't know how to do it with Scanner class. thx

Comment: Honestly, your code and the Scanner documentation didn't give any clear reason why you are not reading symbols, so I assumed that you weren't making it up, agreed with you, and provided a viable alternative. :) I didn't feel like researching the why in depth, when I have used the other approach myself.

Comment: Still can't get the right symbols with the BufferedReader readLine() approach. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an instance of `Scanner` where you pass in a character set, i.e.
`new Scanner (InputStream src, String charsetName)`

HTH

Comment: Hi @Devunwired, I have tried with utf-8 but still get the same result. What charset should I be trying with?