# Images in android textview using fromHtml method doesn't show up

Tags: android, html, image

I'm trying to display images in my help file using the Html.fromHtml method.

This is my java code

```
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.help), new Html.ImageGetter() {
            @Override
             public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                    int id;

                    if (source.equals("top_scrollers.png")) {
                        id = R.drawable.top_scrollers;
                    }
                    else if (source.equals("prices.png")) {
                        id = R.drawable.prices;
                    }
                    else if (source.equals("percentage.png")) {
                        id = R.drawable.percentage;
                    }
                    else if (source.equals("mplus.png")) {
                        id = R.drawable.mplus;
                    }
                    else {
                        return null;
                    }

                    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
                    d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    return d;
                }
        }, null));
```

And this is my xml

```
<string name="help">
<![CDATA[
<h1>Help</h1>
<p>
<h3>Getting stone price</h3>
<img src="top_scrollers.png"/>
</p>
]]>
</string>
```

As you can see i'm placing the images in the cdata text, and I have created a method to create drawables from them, but it is just isn't displayable.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You should try webview for this.

Comment: simply load your htmlform data in webview, like webview.loadData(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.help), "text/html", null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebView instead TextView for it. Try this solution:

1) Put your top_scrollers.png in **assets** folder

2) Create your_html.html in **raw** folder with content:

```
<h1>Help</h1>
<p>
<h3>Getting stone price</h3>
<img src="file:///android_asset/top_scrollers.png"/>
</p>
```

3) For read this raw file as string you can read this 
    [Android read text raw resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file)

4) After that you can load this text in webView:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", your_raw_string, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```