# Read a simple text file

Tags: android

Hi everyone I am trying to read the date from a file in android. I am using Eclipse and the program is compiling and running, just it is not printing the context of the txt file. Here is my load method

```
    private String load(String filename) {
        try {
//          Log.v("Home", " in the load method");
            Log.d("Home", " in the load method");

            final FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
//          final InputStream fis =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pages);

            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            fis.close();
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "No entry exists for this file";
        }
    }
```

and in the oncreate i just access it

```
String fileName = "pages.txt";
load(fileName);
```

pages.txt is in the res/raw directory. I tried to read the file with both

```
final FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
// final InputStream fis =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pages);
```

but It is not printing the context.

I added in the onCreate method

```
Log.d("File", load(fileName));
```

but is returning the catch statement `No entry exists for this file.`

Thanks

Comment: You're currently ignoring the return value of the `load` method. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: Resources must be dealt with via `getResources()`, there is no file named `"pages.txt"` anywhere in the package. Stick to `openRawResource`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5675934/1339473 this link may help you i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use like below,

```
System.out.println(load(raw.pages));



 private String load(int id) {
        try {           
             Resources res = getResources();
             InputStream fis = res.openRawResource(id);
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            fis.close();
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "No entry exists for this file";
        }
    }
```