# How to Load different language html page according to device in web view as we do with string files for different language support

Tags: android, android-layout, internationalization, android-widget

I want to add some html files in different languages in my application for supporting my application for different languages. I have done with string.xml file but now i want to add  html pages on web view according to device language. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes i do when the problem gets resolved..

Comment: but here still i am getting the problem for loading the html file to web view from raw folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you want to store your HTML files in `/res/string`, then you can use language qualifiers to specify for which language the resources is meant, like `/res/string-en` or `/res/string-nl` (for English respectively Dutch files).

Same goes for all other resource types, like `/res/drawable`, `/res/raw/`, etc.

For more information checkout the [Android Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework) pages.

To load the HTML from a string and show it in your `WebView` use the [`loadData()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
html = resources.getString(R.string.my_html_page);
myWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", myEncoding);
```

Comment: OK. I have created the raw folder for different languages, now i am trying to load the html files in web view but don't know how to add the path of these html files in WebView.loadUrl() function? i have used mainHelpWebView.loadUrl(getResources().getString(R.raw.help_main));  and also mainHelpWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(getResources().getString(R.raw.help_main), null, null, null, null); but both are not working

Comment: But it loads the string. I have the html files in the raw folder and want to load these files in web view according to device language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file shows how to read the file content of a `raw` resource.

Comment: I sorted with this problem with  WebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/fileName.html");