# Importing a Text File to my project gives error

Tags: android

**Why when I import a Text File to my project it shows me an error?**

I need the text file to read some info from it and display it on a ListView. Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: Put your text file in `raw` and make its extenstion to something (such as .txt).

Comment: Ok .. I created a a folder called Raw. Dropped the text file there, now how can I reference to it on Java code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file

Comment: @A--C You are always helpful, I appreciate it. If you post your comment as an answer, I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open raw resources, you need to use [`openRawResource()`.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29)

For example, if you're in an `Activity`, you can open the raw text file as:

```
InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
```

This returns an [InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html), which allows you to read from your file.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file) SO question provides a nice code sample for basic reading of a raw text file.

Answer (score 0):

All data files in this directory must be XML format.

There are several kinds of data you can put here.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html for details.

For example:

res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="prefs">Version</string>
```

would be referenced in Java code as

```
String version = context.getResources().getString(R.id.prefs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a textile to fill a ListView, you should set it on strings.xml, add the String name and his value. @String can be stored and retrieved as resources.

Comment: I do not know how to work with XML files. I do not want to confuse you, but this Text File contains an Html Code. I am planning to parse from it using Jsoup library. Do you understand what I am trying to do?