# FileNotFoundException: ENOENT...but, but, but I have a file

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I'm using the following try/catch to try to parse a pipe-separated text file into an array ( each line is like this:  spanishword|englishword|spanishword.mp3 ) for a flashcard app.  Pretty simple, but I'm a complete noob.  Here is what I cobbled together, which leads to the `FileNotFoundException`.

The file is res/raw/first100mostcommon.txt.  I like problem solving and am not really interested in being handed a solution, but a better hint than "file not found" would be appreciated.

I think `String strFile = "R.raw.first100mostcommon";` is the right way to name it; is this right?

```
try 
{
    String strFile = "R.raw.first100mostcommon";

    //create BufferedReader to read pipe-separated variable file

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(strFile));
    String strLine = "";
    StringTokenizer st = null;

    int row = 0; 
    int col = 0;

    //read pipe-separated variable file line by line

    while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        //break pipe-separated variable line using "|"
        st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, "|");

        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            //store pipe-separated variable values
            stWords[row][col] = st.nextToken();
            col++;
        }
        row++;                                   
        //reset token number
        col = 0;                          
    }     
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    text.setText("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);

}
```

Comment: logcat would be nice ;-) other than that, see my solution comingsoon® - edit: no solution: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5675934/2188682

Comment: You should be using proper file seperator. like `/` instead of `.` in `strFile`. Currently compiler looking this as complete file name and not as `filepath`. So most probably its looking in `root` folder where that file is not available causing `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Is your file in the same directory as your `.class` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The file is res/raw/first100mostcommon.txt

That is not a file. That is a raw resource. It exists as a file on your development machine. It exists in an entry in the APK (ZIP archive) on the device.

To access the raw resource stored on your development machine as `res/raw/first100mostcommon.txt`, call `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.first100mostcommon)` on any `Context`, such as your `Activity`. This will return an `InputStream` that you can use to read in the contents.