# How to give the path of any newly added file in Android?

Tags: android

I made a new `data` folder in `res` folder and place the file `left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger` inside it and give the path in the `MaxentTagger` as

```
MaxentTagger tagger = null;
tagger = new MaxentTagger("data/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");
```

I gave the path `data/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger` in constructor.
I also edit the `app.iml` and added this line

```
sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res/data" isTestSource="false" />
```

But still it giving the error

> Loading default properties from trained tagger left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger
>   Error: No such trained tagger config file found.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html on what are the accepted folders under the `res` folder.

Related to your particular case, you can place the file under res/raw folder and you can access it by id (`R.raw.left3words_wsj_0_18` - note the automatic conversion from dash to underline, so you might want to just go ahead and change the file name to avoid confusion later on).

Here is an example on how to read a raw resource:
[Android read text raw resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file)

Comment: @N. T. Should I add folder in `app.iml` file?

Comment: No, you can add it the same way in which you add the other resources. Either through Android Studio (right click on res folder and choose `Add resource directory` and make sure you choose the type `raw`) or through your file explorer (just create folder and add the file there)