# Where to place .glb file and how get path to it in android?

Tags: android, sceneform

I'm trying to set up ARCore scene with Sceneform. There are this piece of code:

```
(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.single_player_ar_fragment) as ArFragment)
            .setOnTapPlaneGlbModel(link)
```

It loads 3d-model with .glb extension by **link**, which is `String`. I can't understand where to put .glb file and how get a path to it. I tried to put it in assets or res folders, but in 2 hours i couldn't find how to get `String` path to it.

I know that these folders have `open()` methods, which returns `InputStream`, but `setOnTapPlaneGlbModel()` needs `String` with a path as an argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android read text raw resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file)

Comment: Or have you seen: https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android/blob/master/samples/3d-model-viewer/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/sceneviewbackground/MainActivity.java

Comment: @MorrisonChang I saw the similar one. I know that i can open file from assets or res folders, but this ```setOnTapPlaneGlbMode``` needs a path which is ```String```.

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes, I have seen their sample. There is a path to .glb file, but i don't know where they did place it, so I could access it like they did

Comment: So putting the files under `assets/model` https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android/tree/master/samples/3d-model-viewer/src/main/assets/models like the same didn't work?

Comment: @MorrisonChang  Yeah, I tried before... It worked now, when I put it in ```Uri.parse()``` and called ```toString()```, which I didn't try before... Thank you :)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I think you could add it as answer so I would accept this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had assumed that the files are in the same location as the sample:
https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android/tree/master/samples/3d-model-viewer/src/main/assets/models

Based on comment thread:

`setOnTapPlaneGlbModel(Uri.parse(link).toString())` seems to resolve to the correct asset location and fix the issue.

References:
https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android/blob/master/samples/3d-model-viewer/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/sceneviewbackground/MainActivity.java