# javaClass.getResourceAsStream returns null even though the file is in the specified location

Tags: android, kotlin, fileinputstream

I am trying to access a .json file in src/main/resources in an android project but I keep getting that the variable input is null

I've made sure that the file is in the specified location.

```
private val CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "src/main/resources/credentials.json"
private var input = javaClass.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Is my syntax wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android read text raw resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file)

Comment: Android apps don’t compile like JVM apps. You have to put your resource in a specific location or it won’t be available in the compiled app. Read the documentation on raw resources.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the advice!!