# Read Input Text File and Compare (Android)

Tags: java, android, data-access

I have this text file named `params.txt` which consist of:

```
3
WENSY WENDY
PING PING
CHLOE CHLOE
```

My question is, how can I read this inputs and compare the two strings in one line? Compare Wensy and Wendy and so on..

`Code:`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    InputStream is=null;
    DataInputStream dis=null;
    Resources myResources = null;
    TextView tv=null;
    String someText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button verify = (Button) findViewById (R.id.verify);
    myResources = this.getResources();
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.FileViewer);
    is = myResources.openRawResource(R.raw.params);
    dis = new DataInputStream(is);
    someText = null;

    verify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                someText=dis.readLine();
                }catch(IOException ioe){
                someText ="Couldn't read the file";
                }
                tv.setText(someText);           
        }
    });


    }


}
```

Can I save the input text on a String variable? Or there's another simple way to do this? thankyou :))

Comment: @newuser code added. I don't know how to compare the two strings.

Answer (score 2):

Try , [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String[] splittedValues = someText.split(" ");
if (splittedValues[0].equalsIgnoreCase(splittedValues[1]))
  {
      // do your process
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344551/how-to-read-text-file-in-android) to figure out how to read the file line by line.

Then to compare the two parts of each line you can seperate them by doing this:

```
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
```

Then you can compare each part using `parts[0]` and `parts[1]`.
Example:

```
if(parts[0].equals(parts[1])) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your someText = dis.readLine();

```
String[] split = someText.split(" ");
if (split[0].equals(split[1]){
    Log.i("MainActivity", "strings are equal");
}else{
    Log.i("MainActivity", "strings are not equal");
}
```

Will compare to see if the strings are equal. otherwise, you could use `String.compareTo(otherString);` for comparisons.