# how to copy content from text file to database in android

Tags: android

I am currently working on an app, where users enter data in given editText fields for one row and add the data to database.

In case of multiple rows (e.g. 50) to add, I want to allow a user to supply data through text files in specific format with delimeters.

How do I select the file or get file path of that text file supplied by the user 
and then use it in my app to add the data to database?

Answer (score 0):

[How can I read a text file from the SD card in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android)

[How to read text file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344551/how-to-read-text-file-in-android)

[Android read text raw resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file)

check these answers for how to load file to your application. Regarding saving inputs to database you can use classic for loop and go through every row and save it to database